# Hiding configuration folder in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm using `unicorn` behind `nginx` and `Rails 4.1`

The issue is that when running in either mode (development/production), if I request:

```
http://my.example.com//config/database.yml
```

I just download the file. No problem! The same happens for every other file in the folder or subfolders.

This should not be allowed. I've been trying to find a way to block this.

So far, I've managed it via `nginx` with this line:

```
rewrite ^/+config/.* / permanent;
```

But I guess... no... I'm certain that there must be a Rails way to do this. Can you show me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI a true rails app will only load from the `public` directory. All the other dirs should not exist to the outside world, as it will all render through `public`. If you see [this example](http://wiki.nginx.org/RubyonRailsMongrel):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root         /var/www/apps/example/current/public;
    index        index.html index.htm;
```

It loads from the public dir. Perhaps you could post your nginx configuration to see what the issue is?